# Ng-repeat Input Fields

Tags: angularjs

So I'm working on a project where I need to form a grid of text input fields, a la an excel spreadsheet to display values and allow them to be updated.

Using angular, the snippet of html that does this with a regular table structure is:

```
<table >
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th ng-repeat="week in weeks">{{week['weekEndDate']}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="field in fields" id={{field['fieldID']}}>
                <td>{{field['displayName']}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="week in weeks" id={{week['weekID']}}>
                    {{ week[field.name] }}
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Where I have a table: weeks (checking, saving, expense) and fields (fieldID, name).  The fields.name column maps directly to the column names in the weeks table.

My thing is, I want these to be  type fields with the same table structure.

I tried:

```
<table >
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th ng-repeat="week in weeks">{{week['weekEndDate']}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="field in fields" id={{field['fieldID']}}>
                <td>{{field['displayName']}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="week in weeks" id={{week['weekID']}}>
                    <input ng-model="{{ week[field.name] }}" placeholder="{{ week[field.name] }}">
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

But that gave me the error of

Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{ week[field.name] }}] starting at [{ week[field.name] }}].

And also, I have buttons that allow you to move forward and backwards by one week at a time, which basically does the same query with different date parameters -- and each time a button is hit, it spawns an additional column of input fields rather than 'replacing' the current one.

So I'm wondering what the proper syntax for this type of desired behavior could be, as it is not liking the way I have it set up.

As always, thanks in advance gals and guys.

Comment: `ng-model` does not take a string expression. Use `ng-model="week[field.name]"`

Comment: >.< ..... I'm both incredibly excited, and incredibly frustrated that it was that easy.... It took longer for me to type that up, than it took to wait for an answer and fix it.

Thank you.. so so much...

Comment: Just try to remember that anything in `{{ ... }}` is a string. Also, [read the fine manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) ;)

Comment: There's no way for me to mark a comment as the answer, is there?

Comment: Nope, I've just voted to close as *"no longer a problem / just a typo"*